# What is the meaning of minimal, netinstall and bin iso

Tags: 12.04

What is the difference between minimal, netinstall and bin iso?

I am confused which ISO image to download.

Comment: For which purpose you want to run Ubuntu? (ex:Desktop, Server etc.) Also from where you are going to download iso?

Comment: where we need to download for desktop or sometime for server.Please guide me.

Comment: netinstall = Core + some tools for download and packaging. (200-400mb)

Answer (score 1):

**Minimal**
The Minimal CD will download packages from online archives at installation time instead of providing them on the install CD itself. Downloading packages at install time reduces the size of the install CD to approximately 5 to 30MB depending on architecture (see below), as well as providing only the packages needed for installation. The download time savings achieved by using a Minimal CD can be significant, as only current packages are downloaded, so there is no need to upgrade packages immediately after installation. The Minimal CD uses a text-based installer like the Alternate CD, making the CD image as compact as possible.
*https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD*

**Netinstall**
The network installer lets you install Ubuntu over the network. This is useful, for example, if you have an old machine with a non-bootable CD-ROM or a computer that can’t run the graphical interface-based installer, either because they don’t meet the minimum requirements for the live CD/DVD or because they require extra configuration before the graphical desktop can be used, or if you want to install Ubuntu on a large number of computers at once.
*http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads*

**Bin ISO**
That would then just be the normal one (as far as I understood it)

I'd just go with the normal iso (:

Comment: for desktop user which we should use

Comment: For a Desktop/Laptop I'd just use the normal one found here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop (for the 14.04) or if you want the 12.04 as your title says here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ (and there at the "Desktop CD" section the Intel x86 for a 32bit or AMD64 for a 64bit version)

Comment: bin for what purpose we used